# Show that $\mathbb{R}^2/{\sim}$ is homeomorphic to the sphere $S^2$.

Tags: general-topology

$\mathbb{R}^2/{\sim}$ is the smallest equivalence relation such that $P\sim Q$ for all $P,Q$ with $\|P\|_2,\|Q\|_2 \geq 1$. Show that $\mathbb{R}^2/{\sim}$ is homeomorphic to the sphere $S^2$.

---

Attempt:

$\mathbb{R}^2/{\sim}=A\cup B$ where $A:=\{\{P\}:\|P\|_2<1\}$ and $B:=\{\{P:\|P\|_2\geq1\}\}$. I think $A$ corresponds to a unit open disk and we can deform it to the sphere substracted a point $x$ and also $x$ corresponds to the element of $B$. But I cannot explicitly write the homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^2/{\sim}$ and $S^2$.

Edit: Formally we have $\mathbb{R}^2/{\sim}\supseteq A\simeq \mathbb{B}^2\simeq\mathbb{R}^2\simeq S^2-\{x\}\subseteq S^2$ where $\mathbb{B}^2$ is the unit open disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Clearly we can extend the homeomorphism between $A$ and $S^2-\{x\}$ to the bijection from $\mathbb{R}^2/{\sim}$ to $S^2$. How can we show this bijection is actually a homeomorphism?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Riemann sphere $\widehat{\mathbb C}= \mathbb R^2\cup \{\infty\}$ which is homeomorphic to $S^2$ ?

Comment: Use `\|` rather than `||` for the norm; and use `{\sim}` to remove the excessive spacing around `\sim`.

Comment: @Bebop In $\mathbb{R}^3$ there is a stereographic projection between $S^2 - \{x\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$. And we can extend it to a homeomorphism $S^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\cup\{\infty\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of $S^2$, one can work with the Riemann sphere $\widehat{\mathbb C}=\mathbb R^2\cup\{\infty\}$ and show that $\mathbb R^2/ {\sim}$ is homeomorphic to $\widehat{\mathbb C}$.

Consider the following map : $$\begin{array}{rrcl}\varphi: & \mathbb R^2 & \longrightarrow & \widehat{\mathbb C} \\ & x & \longmapsto & \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} \dfrac{x}{1-\|x\|} & \text{ if } \|x\|<1 \\ \infty & \text{ if } \|x\|\geq 1\end{array}\right. \end{array} $$

$\varphi$ is continuous and constant on each equivalence classes thus it definies a well defined continuous map $\overline{\varphi}$ from $\mathbb R^2/{\sim}$ to $\widehat{\mathbb C}$.

Moreover, one can easily check that :

1. $\overline{\varphi}$ is now bijective,
2. $\mathbb R^2/{\sim}$ is Hausdorff.
3. Let $\pi:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R^2/{\sim}$ be the canonical projection and $B$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathbb R^2$. Then $\pi(B)=\mathbb R^2/{\sim}$ and thus $\mathbb R^2/{\sim}$ is a compact space.

Hence, $\overline{\varphi}$ is a continuous  bijective map from a compact space into a Hausdorff space so, it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: How can we show $\varphi$ is surjective?

Comment: Use the polar coordinates : let $x\in \mathbb R^2$ s.t. $0<\|x\|<1$ then one can write $x=(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))$ and $\varphi(x)=\phi(r)\cdot (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$ with $\phi(r)=\frac{r}{1-r}, r\in (0,1)$. Now, check that any non zero vector $y\in \mathbb R^2$ can be written as $y=\phi(r)\cdot (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$.

Comment: Clearly, $\varphi$ is continuous on the open unit disk. Suppose $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\|x\|\geq 1$. How can we show that $\varphi$ is continuous at $x$?

Comment: Do you mean $\varphi$ ? $\varphi$ is constant on $\{x\in\mathbb R^2: \|x\|\geq 1\}$ and if $x$ belongs to the unit circle you can easily check that $\displaystyle \lim_{y\to x, \|y\|<1} \varphi(y)=\infty$.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't realize this :) Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't completely comfortable working with quotient spaces, the following is very useful.

**Universal property of the quotient space**

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, and let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on the points of $X$.  Then we have a natural continuous map $p\colon X\to X/{\sim}$ given by projecting a point of $X$ on to its equivalence class.

Now, let $g\colon X/{\sim}\to Y$ be a continuous map.  By composing with $p$, we get a continuous map from $X$ to $Y$:

$$
g\circ p\colon X\xrightarrow{p}X/{\sim}\xrightarrow{g}Y
$$

Write $f=g\circ p$.  Now $f$ isn't just any old continuous map from $X$ to $Y$; it has a special property; namely, that if $x\sim y$ then $f(x)=f(y)$.  [This is because $p(x)=p(y)$.]

Why is this interesting?  Well, it gives us a characterization of the continuous maps from $X/{\sim}\to Y$:

> if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a continuous map such that
>
> (*) $f(x)=f(y)$ whenever $x\sim y$
>
> then there is a unique continuous map $g\colon X/{\sim}\to Y$ such that $f=g\circ p$.

In other words, the following map of sets is a bijection:

\begin{align}
\{\textrm{Continuous maps }g\textrm{ from }X/{\sim}\textrm{ to }Y\}&\to\{\textrm{Continuous maps }f\textrm{ from }X\textrm{ to }Y\textrm{ satisfying (*)}\} \\
g&\mapsto g\circ p
\end{align}

So, coming up with a continuous map from $X/{\sim}$ to $Y$ is the same thing as coming up with a continuous map from $X$ to $Y$ that is constant on equivalence classes.

**This particular example**

Here, you want to define a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R^2/{\sim}$ to $S^2$, where $\sim$ identifies all points whose norm is at least $1$.  By the above discussion, we need to specify a continuous map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $S^2$ that is constant outside the open unit disc.  Clearly, in order to do this, it is enough to define a continuous map from the closed disc $D^1=\{P\in\mathbb R^2\;\colon\;\|P\|\le 1\}$ to $S^2$ and then extend it by the constant value everywhere else.

Can you think of a suitable map?  It should be surjective, and it should be injective except on the boundary of the disc, where it should take some constant value.

**Hint:** Remember that the closed disc $D^1$ can be parameterized by polar coordinates $(\rho,\vartheta)$, and that the sphere $S^2$ can be parameterized by spherical polar coordinates $(\phi, \theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

The sphere $S^2$ is the set of all points 
$$\left\{\pmatrix{\cos \phi\\ \sin\phi\cos\theta\\ \sin\phi\sin\theta}\middle| \array{0\le\phi\le\pi,\\0\le\theta\le2\pi} \right\}$$
The plane $R^2$ can be written as the set 
$$\left\{\pmatrix{r\cos\sigma\\ r\sin\sigma}\middle| \array{0\le r\\ 0\le\sigma\le 2\pi}\right\}$$
There is a function $R^2\to S^2$ sending 
$$\pmatrix{r\cos\sigma\\ r\sin\sigma}\mapsto\pmatrix{\cos(\pi\min(r,1))\\ \sin(\pi\min(r,1))\cos\sigma\\ \sin(\pi\min(r,1))\sin\sigma}$$
Can you show this map is continuous and induces a homeomorphism $R^2/{\sim} \to S^2$ ?