# Show that $S^n$ is homeomorphic to $(D^n\times \{-1, 1\})/{\sim}$, where $(x, 1)\sim (x, -1)$ for all $x$ in boundary of $D^n$

Tags: general-topology

I understand some basic examples of homeomorphisms such as [Show that $\mathbb{R}^2/{\sim}$ is homeomorphic to the sphere $S^2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381165/show-that-mathbbr2-sim-is-homeomorphic-to-the-sphere-s2) but I don't know where to start with this example. Do I have to consider/construct a quotient map in order to define a homeomorphism? Looking for some hints/starts.

$D^n$ is the disc $D^n = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x| \leq 1 \}$

**Edit**: Still looking for help on this.

Comment: What is $D^n$, and what is the basis of it? Up to homeomorphism, probably the closed $n$-ball and its boundary, but can you give the definitions you use?

Comment: @DanielFischer Edited to add the definitions, thanks.

Comment: Can you map $D^n$ homeomorphically to a closed hemisphere of $S^n$?

Comment: Yes that is possible, but I can't think of an explicit mapping

Comment: You can fairly easily find an explicit map if you consider $D^n$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $D^n = \{(x_1,\dotsc,x_n,0) : x_1^2 + \dotsc + x_n^2 \leqslant 1\}$, and $S^n$ as the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: Note that if you construct a continuous bijection $D^n\times \{-1,1\}/{\sim}\to S^n$, it will automatically be a homeomorphism since the domain is compact and the codomain is Hausdorff.  This lets you avoid having to muck around with exactly what the quotient topology looks like.